# Tensorflow: unsupported callable error when printing predicted variable from DNNClassifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am training a dataset which is similar to mnist

System:MacOS

Tensorflow Version: 1.13.1(from Anaconda)

`x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train`, `y_test` are pandas dataframes that are already exists

My code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[28 * 28])]

# DNN model for training
dnn_clf=tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[300,100,20],
                                            n_classes=10)
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": x_train.values}, y=y_train.values, num_epochs=5, batch_size=50, shuffle=True)

# Train the training set
dnn_clf.train(input_fn=input_fn)

# Predict the test set
pred_test=dnn_clf.predict(x_test.values)
print(list(pred_test))
```

I need these predicted value instead of `dnn_clf.evaluate` function in the tutorial because I want to make a confusion matrix of that model.

The error happens in the last line, and part of the long error message as the following screenshot:

The final error message I got is:

```
TypeError: unsupported callable
```

[image]

So how can I get the predicted value correctly in `DNNClassifier` in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

The bug happens in the 'predict' part of the above code, it should be:

```
test_value = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": x_test}, y=None, batch_size=50, shuffle=True)
pred_test=dnn_clf.predict(input_fn=test_value)
```

it returns a generator instead of a list

So the way to get a predicted value is(maybe it is not correct enough, if there are anything wrong, please tell me):

1.Convert the generator into a list

```
pred_info=list(pred_test)
```

2.Each element in this list looks like this:

```
{'logits': array([ -0.88073593,  -7.3466268 ,   3.0595555 ,   0.8544391 ,
          6.690731  , -12.812279  ,   7.951861  , -15.16283   ,
         -0.11098857, -12.9959545 ], dtype=float32),
 'probabilities': array([1.12913796e-04, 1.75649234e-07, 5.80756133e-03, 6.40212209e-04,
        2.19277114e-01, 7.42923278e-10, 7.73918152e-01, 7.08128972e-11,
        2.43805902e-04, 6.18264884e-10], dtype=float32),
 'class_ids': array([6]),
 'classes': array([b'6'], dtype=object)}
```

'class_ids' is what we want

each element in this list is a dictionary

So do dict_item_want.get() method for each element in this list like this

```
dnn_test=[]
for i in pred_info:
    dnn_test.append(int(i.get('class_ids')))
print('the first 10 predictions from DNNClassifier are:')
```

And you can get a list

3.Apply confusion matrix to this list and y value in the test set